# Official name for {{ }} in blade laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-blade

In blade laravel, you can add a variable to a sentence for example like so

```
$dogName = "Jack";

<p>My dogs name is {{$dogName}}
```

What is the offical name for "{{ }}"

Comment: I've seen this generically called "Mustache" syntax..

Answer (score 5):

In [the docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/blade) it is called "Double curly brace syntax":

> Be very careful when echoing content that is supplied by users of your application. Always use the escaped, `double curly brace syntax` to prevent XSS attacks when displaying user supplied data.